# how to compare elements in an array?

Tags: arrays

```
int elements[5] = {1,2,5,1,2} 

for(int i=0; i< 5 -1 ; i++)
  {
     if(elements[i] ==elements[i+1]  ){
          cout << "equal" << endl;
     }else{

      cout << "not equal" << endl;
     }

  }
```

How to improve this? I cannot compare index 0 to index 5;

Comment: What do you want? To compare each element with each element? Then you need inner loop. Or, you can sort array first and have one loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
int elements[5] = {1,2,5,1,2} 
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
   for(int j=i+1; j<5; j++)
      {
          if(elements[i] ==elements[j]  ){
               cout << "equal" << endl;
          }else{
               cout << "not equal" << endl;
          }
      }
   }
```